# How to make Autofill more efficient, or an alternative to Autofill

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a document that needs to `autofill` a selection of cells down an area that is changing, although it will regularly be upwards of 25000 or more rows. The cells that I am attempting to `autofill` downwards are filled with "complex" formulas, that are configured to work with `autofill`.

When I have more than 15000 rows, to run one instance of

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

this will take upwards of 20 minutes to completely execute this one line, so if I need to run this 5 times for an example, we're looking an estimated 100 minutes of run time for 5 lines of code.

I'm curious if there's a more efficient way to either use `AutoFill`, or execute the task I'm looking to achieve.

I haven't really found much that was helpful, I did change my range a few times to see if that increases or reduces times.

If I change `LastRow` to be equal to say, `50-1000` this line of code runs instantaneously. Once we creep above the `1000` rows, this starts to run incredibly slow.

Ideally, If I can find an additional way to run this that would significantly decrease my run times, that would be great.

Comment: You can try having the sheet in a table format and as new entries are added to the dataset the formulas will carry down automatically without the help of a macro. you can do this by highlighting your dataset and hitting `CTRL + T`

Comment: alternatively, you can turn off screen updating and other functions to speed things along and turn them back on at the end

Comment: Hi Mark, I went ahead and tested the table methodology and this doesn't bring my formulas down. 

I'm specifically only adding entires into two columns when there are upwards of 50+ in this specific sheet.

Comment: When you did the table, drag down the formula to the end of the table, and any new entries should get that formula. Alternatively, delete all but one of the spots and as you hit enter it should go down.

Comment: Alas, I think since I'm attempting to take formulas in rows 1-4 and reiterate these formulas down the sheet, I don't think this method will work.

Comment: Oh so it's a different set of formulas for each row? Nevermind my method then, unless you're using a nested `IF` function

Answer (score 0):

There are some boilerplate code I use frequently to squeeze a better performance out of my VBA code:

```
Sub Test()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Code here
....

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False` makes your spreadsheet not jump around. Can't provide you with hard data here, but from my personal experience updating the screen slows down your macro quite significantly.

`Application.Calculation` controls how calculation is handled, and is defaulted to `xlCalculationAutomatic`. Under this default setting, all formula field gets updated when there is a change in value of a referenced cell. Setting it to `xlCalculationManual` before running your VBA, then back to `xlCalculationAutomatic` will ensure that calculations are only performed one time, instead of throughout your script when numbers are changing all the time.

`Application.EnableEvents` controls codes that is triggered by event (like saving, or activating a worksheet). Just in case, I set it to `False`.

Remember to set everything back to their default values at the end of your vba, or under your `ErrorHandler` section of your VBA.

***Just FYI, having these two application settings changed makes it a harder to debug your code if you rely on looking at your spreadsheet to debug. Best to completely remove them during debugging, and add them back once you are ready to push to production.***

---

Without your specific formula, it is hard to further optimize. There is one other way you may try that MAY speed things up.

```
Sub MyAutoFill()

My_Formula = "SUM(1,3)" 'Replace this with your complex formula, remember to escape your inverted commas

Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A" & LastRow) = "=" & My_Formula

End Sub
```

The above code sets the values of a range to a string the begins with "=", which becomes an excel formula on the worksheet. This MAY be more efficient than autofill, try it out and report back!